# Replacing <img> with <math> change minus to question mark

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I want to replace `<span><img src="images/image01.png></span>` with a MathML(image01.xml) like below:

```
<math>
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow>
          <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
          <mi>n</mi>
          <mo>−</mo>
          <mn>1</mn>
          <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
          <mo>×</mo>
          <mi>n</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

Using below code to replace (changed the code based on Rufus L's suggestion):

```
string newStr = File.ReadAllText(path to image01.xml);
span.InnerHtml = newStr;
```

After replacing, the embeded MathML is different- `<mo>−</mo>` changes to `<mo>?</mo>`

```
<math>
  <semantics>
    <mrow>
      <mfrac>
        <mrow>
          <mo stretchy="false">(</mo>
          <mi>n</mi>
          <mo>?</mo>
          <mn>1</mn>
          <mo stretchy="false">)</mo>
          <mo>×</mo>
          <mi>n</mi>
        </mrow>
        <mn>2</mn>
      </mfrac>
    </mrow>
  </semantics>
</math>
```

What's wrong with my code? I will fell very appreciated for any help.

```
==============================================================
```

Update:
the newStr is (from Debug, the minus is still there):

```
"<math>\r\n  <semantics>\r\n    <mrow>\r\n      <mfrac>\r\n        <mrow>\r\n          <mo stretchy=\"false\">(</mo>\r\n          <mi>n</mi>\r\n          <mo>−</mo>\r\n          <mn>1</mn>\r\n          <mo stretchy=\"false\">)</mo>\r\n          <mo>×</mo>\r\n          <mi>n</mi>\r\n        </mrow>\r\n        <mn>2</mn>\r\n      </mfrac>\r\n    </mrow>\r\n  </semantics>\r\n</math>"
```

The code for retrieving span is:

```
var spans = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[img]");
foreach (HtmlNode span in spans)
{
    // handle span here
}
```

Comment: Why bother calling  the `Replace` method on the entire string? This code would be more readable: `span.InnerHtml = newStr;`

Comment: Why did you not show the value used for `newStr` and how do you get the value of `span`?

Comment: @luuk I bet that won’t really help as bug is in saving code... which is also not present in the post.

Comment: @Luuk, newStr is "<math>\r\n  <semantics>\r\n    <mrow>\r\n      <mfrac>\r\n        <mrow>\r\n          <mo stretchy=\"false\">(</mo>\r\n          <mi>n</mi>\r\n          <mo>−</mo>\r\n          <mn>1</mn>\r\n          <mo stretchy=\"false\">)</mo>\r\n          <mo>×</mo>\r\n          <mi>n</mi>\r\n        </mrow>\r\n        <mn>2</mn>\r\n      </mfrac>\r\n    </mrow>\r\n  </semantics>\r\n</math>"

Answer (score 0):

What about handling the span as:

```
var mo = span.SelectNode("//mo")
if (mo.innerText=="-") { mo.innerText = "?"; }
```

(untested...)

Comment: thank you, but '-' sign is dynamically parsed from docx, hardcode may not a good solution, I investigate the code deeper, and found the '-' is originally a '&#x2212;' in xml, after I manipulate the xml and save using XmlDocument, '&#x2212;' changes to '-', after replace using HtmlAgilityPack, it changes to '?'.

Comment: LOL, that info was (again) missing from your question. Another example (in general) of 'think before you ask'!